# Not using Sender Authentication Package

Tags: marketing-cloud

We would like to use the existing email domain that we have for Marketing cloud email send. This email domain is already in use.

Are the steps as simple as create a new From address and validate the domain? Are we missing any obvious red flags.

Do we need to follow any specific steps or there are deliverability issues with this approach?

Daily email volume will be less than 50000.

Thanks.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question. Is the existing email domain part of the SAP, or a Private Domain used for sending? Are you just wanting to change the address part of the email address (before the @ character)?

Comment: Thanks.The existing email domain is not part of SAP,This is a corporate email domain like example.mycompany.com .

Comment: Reading through this again, regarding your comment of "email domain is already in use", do you mean that this is your company email address which you use to send and receive email (e.g.  using Outlook)?

Answer (score 1):

If your SAP domain is example.mycompany.com, your from address would need to be [something]@example.mycompany.com (where [something] can be any alphanumeric string).

Alternatively, you could use [something]@mycompany.com or **any** subdomain like [something]@offers.mycompany.com **providing** you have have mycompany.com set up as private domain.

However, if your SAP domain is example.mycompany.com and your from address is [something]@othercompany.com, this will fail DMARC validation.

You will note that there is a new verification tool in the current release, where you can verify a domain in the Sender Profile. [Refer to documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_domain_verification.htm&type=5).

However, if you do **not have SAP enabled** (which your title infers), you would need to have a Private Domain for the email domain that you intend to use (but bear in mind, link tracking, images, etc would use a generic exacttarget.com domain). This would need to be used with a shared IP address pool.

But please note that if you are sending more than 100k messages/month (the minimum needed to keep a dedicated IP ramped up), I would recommend you use an SAP, which will give you a private IP address and link/image  branding.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answers your question, then please accept it for the benefit of others. If it doesn't, then please provide further information so I can assist further.

Comment: Hi Eliot,apologies,I am new to the forum,How do I accept.